# In iOS, how do I parse a JSON string into an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I come from Android dev, so sorry if I'm missing obvious iOS concepts here.

I have a JSON feed that looks like:

`{"directory":[{"id":0,"fName":"...","lName":"...","title":"...","dept":"...","bld":"...","room":"...","email":"...","phone":"..."},{"id":1,"fName":"...","lName":"...","title":"...","dept":"...","bld":"...","room":"...","email":"...","phone":"..."}]}`

Then, I have a Staff.h and .m with a class with properties to match it (id, fName, lName) ect.

I've been working at this for hours, but I can't seem to parse the JSON string to an array of Staff objects. The end goal is to get them into Core Data, so any advice would be nice.

Tutorials I've read haven't shown how to work with a JSON string in the form of {"directory":[{...}]} I had no problem doing this in my Android app, but I'm out of ideas here for iOS (6) in objective-c.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Take a look at [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to see how you can deserialize JSON into native objects from which you can get data.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it like

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:&error];//response object is your response from server as NSData

if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){ //Added instrospection as suggested in comment.
    NSArray *yourStaffDictionaryArray = json[@"directory"];
    if ([yourStaffDictionaryArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){//Added instrospection as suggested in comment.
        for (NSDictionary *dictionary in yourStaffDictionaryArray) {
            Staff *staff = [[Staff alloc] init];
            staff.id = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
            staff.fname = [dictionary objectForKey:@"fName"];
            staff.lname = [dictionary objectForKey:@"lName"]; 
            //Do this for all property
            [yourArray addObject:staff];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I was confused how to get the directory array as you did on the second line.

Comment: as in the second line, you can also use for all others as : `dictionary[@"id"]`, `dictionary[@"fName"]`.. just to shorten the code. **And always do a class introspection/check before typecasting**

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Please update answer with introspection, I am not aware about that.

Comment: jsonObjWithData returns `id`. therefore we should use `if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])` and then move into the loop. Similarly before storing to array we need to check if objForKey/valueFK returns you an array or not.   This is safe programming, as no one knows at times you get incorrect data from response and end up with crash!!!

Answer (score 4):

Use: [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> You use the NSJSONSerialization class to convert JSON to Foundation
>   objects and convert Foundation objects to JSON.
>
> ```
> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following properties:
>
> The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
> All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.
> All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
> Numbers are not NaN or infinity.
> ```

You will get NSDictionary then you can parse (create) it to your object and then use it in CoreData.

Answer (score 3):

Use following code:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

This will covert json data onto NSDictionary, which is similar to hashmap on android. I think this will help you. :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `NSJSonSerialisation` or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library. Here is the example of AFNetworking to parse json response

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    NSDictionary *json = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
    NSArray *staffArray = json[@"directory"];

[staffArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
      Staff *staff = [[Staff alloc] init];
    staff.id = [[obj objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
    staff.fname = [obj objectForKey:@"fName"];
    staff.lname = [obj objectForKey:@"lName"]; 

   //add data to new array to store details
   [detailsArray addObect:staff);
} ];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

then use `Core Data framework` to store data.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [RestKit](http://restkit.org/). It provides object-mapping and CoreData backed storage.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can [SBJSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) framework.

You have to convert the response string into an NSDictionary like

```
 NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dic = [responseString JSONValue];
```

Now you can create an object for **Staff** class.

```
Staff *staff = [[Staff alloc]init];
```

Then you can store values in this object like

```
staff.firstname = [[[dic objectForKey:@"directory"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"fName"];
```

Now you can pass this single object to other classes

Answer (score 1):

You can use the handmade solution proposed by @janak-nirmal, or use a library like jastor, https://github.com/elado/jastor, it doesn't make much difference.
I warn you against Restkit, because the ratio benefits-vs-pain is very low, in my opinion.
Moreover, it could be as use a tank to kill a fly in your scenario.