# how to read json within json in ios

Tags: ios, json

i have the being fetched, i need to read whats inside `data` under `sources`

```
  "id": "cus_7nDkZw63KvTuy5",
  "object": "customer",
  "account_balance": 0,
  "created": 1453839669,
  "currency": "usd",
  "default_source": "card_17XdJE2eZvKYlo2CBNnle4YM",
  "delinquent": false,
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "email": "someone@example.com",
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "shipping": null,
  "sources": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "card_17XdJE2eZvKYlo2CBNnle4YM",
        "object": "card",
        "address_city": null,
        "address_country": null,
        "address_line1": null,
        "address_line1_check": null,
        "address_line2": null,
        "address_state": null,
        "address_zip": null,
        "address_zip_check": null,
        "brand": "Visa",
        "country": "US",
        "customer": "cus_7nDkZw63KvTuy5",
        "cvc_check": "pass",
        "dynamic_last4": null,
        "exp_month": 12,
        "exp_year": 2016,
        "funding": "credit",
        "last4": "4242",
        "metadata": {
        },
        "name": "someone@example.com",
        "tokenization_method": null
      }
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 1,
    "url": "/v1/customers/cus_7nDkZw63KvTuy5/sources"
  },
  "subscriptions": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [

    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/customers/cus_7nDkZw63KvTuy5/subscriptions"
  }
}
```

Comment: NSDictionary *dictn_sources =  [dictn objectForKey:@"sources"]; NSArray *data_arr = [dictn_sources objectForKey: @"data"];

Comment: JSON within JSON will be converted like Dictionary containing dictionary.

Comment: You need to parse JSON string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374986/in-ios-how-do-i-parse-a-json-string-into-an-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code you will get array

```
 [[[[result objectForKey:@"sources"] objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"country"];
```

you will get US as answer.

Comment: By this code he will not get the array , he will get the 1st object of array.

Comment: "response" object you are getting after serialisation